# How to force Composer to download a local package?

Tags: php, composer-php

Let's say we have the following directory structure, we assume `my-package` also exists on Packagist:

```
- apps
\_ my-app
  \_ composer.json
- packages
\_ my-package
  \_ composer.json
```

To add `my/package` as a dependency of my-app, [the documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#path) states we can use the following configuration:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "../../packages/my-package"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "my/package": "*"
    }
}
```

However when I `composer update`, the dependency is still downloaded from Packagist. So, to see, I disabled Packagist.org:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "../../packages/my-package",
            "packagist.org": false
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "my/package": "*"
    }
}
```

I cleared the cache with `composer clearcache`, removed `my/package` with `composer remove my/package` and installed it again with `composer require my/package --prefer-source` (I didn't understand if `--prefer-source` is for vcs only). The downloaded package is still not the local one. How to force composer to use the local one?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
"require": {
    "my/package": "*"
}
```

In case of `VCS` or `path` repository types, you need to specify version of the package you request. So instead of using `*`, as you have currently, use `@dev`:

```
"require": {
    "my/package": "@dev"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For

```
composer --version
Composer version 2.0.14
```

in composer.json file

```
"require": {
"my/package": "dev-master"
}
```