# Force composer to symlink local package

Tags: composer-php

I'm trying to find a proper way to force composer to
symlink local packages.

I know there is a question [How to force Composer to download a local package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41782242/how-to-force-composer-to-download-a-local-package) but it does not answer my questions. I need to make sure it works as expected because I'm going to use this in CI workflow.

**Having project's composer.json like:**

```
{
    "name": "Some project",
    "type": "project",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "repositories": [{
        "type": "path", 
        "url": "packages/*/*"
    }]
}
```

**And package's composer.json (packages/sample/package):**

```
{
    "name": "Sample package",
    "version": "1.0.0"
}
```

**Let's assume that:**

- `sample/package:1.0.0` is published in packagist (commit `aaaaaa`) - with unmodified `composer.json`
- `sample/package` locally is checked out on commit `bbbbbb`
- I can't modify `version` of `sample/package` locally

*Command 1:*

```
$ composer require sample/package
```

Package is fetched from packagist (version `1.0.0`, commit `aaaaaa`).

*Command 2:*

```
$ composer require sample/package:@dev
```

Package is symlinked from local version to vendor directory (version `1.0.0`, commit `bbbbbb`, symlinked).

**Questions are:**

1. Why *Command 1* downloads the package from packagist despite `minimum-stability` option? Version constraint `@dev` lets you enforce different stability but it's already down to `dev` with project config.
2. Will *Command 2* create a symlink to the local package in every case?
3. Is there a better way than *Command 2* to make sure the local package gets symlinked?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## Why Command 1 downloads package from packagist despite minimum-stability option? Version constraint @dev lets you enforce different stability but it already down to dev with project config.

My best educated guess would be that when no version constraint is provided in `composer require sample/package`, Composer will still try to find a stable version to install, because of `"prefer-stable": true`. When you set this option to `false` (or provide `@dev` version constraint for the package explicitly) you should see Composer using the latest available version (`dev-master` on commit `bbbbbb`).

## Will Command 2 create symlink to local package in every case?

Not in every case. You can force Composer to always symlink packages using `"symlink": true` option.

From https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#path:

> The local package will be symlinked if possible, in which case the output in the console will read Symlinked from `../../packages/my-package`. If symlinking is not possible the package will be copied. In that case, the console will output Mirrored from `../../packages/my-package`.
>
> Instead of default fallback strategy you can force to use symlink with `"symlink": true` or mirroring with `"symlink": false` option. Forcing mirroring can be useful when deploying or generating package from a monolithic repository.

## Is there a better way than Command 2 to make sure local package gets symlinked?

You should probably avoid dropping `"prefer-stable": true` from `composer.json` as this would affect all dependencies.

I'd suggest to just make sure you explicitly require `@dev` version for `sample/package` and set `"symlink": true` for the local repository. This would result in something like:

```
{
    "name": "Some project",
    "type": "project",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "repositories": [{
        "type": "path", 
        "url": "packages/*/*",
        "symlink": true
    }],
    "require": {
        "sample/package": "@dev"
    }

}
```

Comment: none of the above worked for me ((

Comment: I guess these solutions don't work on Windows 10

Answer (score 8):

Another reason this might not work, is when you have multiple entries in  `repository`. Composer will use the repository definition it first finds the package in.

In our case, we use a custom Satis repository. When defining the local package after the satis repo, it would never symlink and always use the Satis version. When defining the local package first, it does work.

Working example:

```
    "repositories": {
        "our/local-package": {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "../../some-local-package",
            "options": {
                "symlink": true
            }
        },
        "satis": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "http://our.satis.url/"
        }
    }
```

And then call `composer require our/local-package:@dev`

Comment: Also, you might want to run `composer remove your-package` and then `composer install your-package` to force composer to reinstall the package. Otherwise it does not always seem to detect changes and does nothing.

Answer (score 6):

If the very useful information provided by @Maciek Lewkowicz doesn't work, maybe you are in this situation:

1. You are using a specific branch (for example, `dev-master`);
2. The branch you are using is from your remote repository;
3. You are trying to symlink the same branch, but this time using the path (so, the only thing you changed in `composer.json` was the source of the package, setting the repo in the `repositories` key of the `composer.json` file).

In this situation a simple `composer update` will not work: Composer will not intercept the change: for Composer is irrelevant that you changed the repository from the remote to the local path one. It only checks that the branch is the same and so doesn't update at all.

So, in this case, nothing will work: it will not work to use `symlink: force` nor it will work to change the preferences about the source and so on.

The only thing that will work is to change the branch.

So, for example, your `composer.json` will be something like this:

```json
{
    ...
    "require": {
        ...
-       "your/package": "dev-master",
+       "your/package": "dev-dev",
        ...
    },
    ...
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "/Path/To/Your/Local/package"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here `dev-dev` is a new branch called `dev`: changing the branch from `dev-master` to `dev-dev` will force Composer to download again the package as the required branch is not `dev-master` anymore.

In downloading again the package, Composer will also check that the new source is now a local path and so it will symlink the folder.

Also note that `composer install` will not work, also if you change the branch name.

**YOU HAVE TO USE `composer update`.**

Comment: Didn't work for me. It says: Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages - Root composer.json requires foo/bar dev-dev, found foo/bar[dev-master] but it does not match the constraint.

Comment: You have a conflict on packages: you should go deeper in this issue and find compatible versions.

Answer (score 0):

To expand a little bit on the already great answers here, I ran into the same problem but the solution was slightly different:

When you have the same "version" available (branch, tag, hash) in your local package AND in a remote repo, in case composer can not resolve the dependencies of your local package, it will just silently drag the version from the remote repo, as long as those dependencies can be resolved.

In order to debug this you can add some weirdo version (e.g. `100`) to the "version" attribute of your local packages `package.json` and then require it with that version, thus showing you which dependency can not be fulfilled (and you change that then).