# What steps do I take to create a local copy of a package in Composer for modification?

Tags: php, composer-php, mpdf

Are there any instructions how to create a local copy of a package (here Mpdf) for modification? I tried this, but composer autoload uses the original version in the `vendor` directory when constructing the Mpdf object, even if I add an entry in section `autoload/psr-4` in file `composer.json`.

Modifying the original version in the `vendor` directory doesn't seem an appropriate solution to me since it is not part of the main repository and might be overwritten when updating mPDF with composer.

Link to feature request: https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/issues/1880

Comment: Fork the repository, then add to your composer.json that new repository and tell that it has the wanted version of the dependency. If you operate with a local clone, Composer can even symlink into the vendor folder, so you can easily patch things.  Composer: [How to force Composer to download a local package?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41782242/367456). This is also what [Matěj Humpál](https://github.com/finwe) [replied to you](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/issues/1880#issuecomment-1575612904): [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] _"If you need to modify the writer ad hoc, just create a fork and use the fork in composer (see [repositories](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#loading-a-package-from-a-vcs-repository))."_ --- And never edit files within the `vendor` directory, that makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 0):

not to use main composer file, you can create a new folder any place and make a composer.json file include your lib which you want to load in that composer and autoload composer file in the souce code, this was you will never touch the main composer file. and you can do this as many time you want.